# Oversized display in monitor when connected by VGA from windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution, vga

So I have ASUS laptop A455LF i5-5200u with Intel HD Graphics 5500 and Nvidia GT930M running latest update of Windows 10 and latest update of every graphic driver connected to LG 22MN42A monitor + tv via HDMI. It got full HD resolution at 1920x1080 but the quality is so bad, text has white shadow, some text looks blurry, color looks odd. But when I try to connect via VGA cable, everything became so much better with sharp text and natural color. One problem is, no matter which display resolution I choose, each of it will get oversized in the monitor, just reduced in quality when I choose smaller resolution. When I see resolution detail of my LG monitor+tv on its website, it says "PC/Analog 1366x768" and "Video/HDMI 1920x1080". Is there any meaning of this? Please help me everyone, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the manual for a control called "Overscan" & disable it.

That will fix the 'zoomed' aspect you are seeing, but nothing is really going to fix the fact that you're trying to make a low-end TV with a basic 480i picture quality into a computer monitor.
It attempts to show you 1920x1080 over HDMI by simply stretching the picture to fit - might be kind of OK for a television picture, but awful for a computer monitor.
Its nominal display size [actual pixel count] is only 1366x768, which is not "Full HD", so your 'best picture' is going to be at that resolution.

Comment: I see, so the 480i thing means something. Thank you. I will use this for tv use only, I guess I need to buy a new real monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the display is determined by the screen.

PC/Analog 1366x768: When the PC or Analog signal is input, the maximum resolution that the host outputs to the monitor is 1366x768.

Video/HDMI 1920x1080: When the Video or HDMI signal is input, the maximum resolution that the host outputs to the monitor is 1920x1080.

Try the following method:

1. It is recommended to use an HDMI cable.
2. Try changing the screen mode to the extended mode so that we can set the resolution of the two screens separately.
3. Adjust the resolution of the TV to 1920*1080.

Comment: But why is the display quality of HDMI output looks so bad. Is it because my laptop's native resolution is 1366x768?